# Find rows not used by xml column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a `status` table, and I must find the unused statuses.
The status code can be used in activity templates, which have an `actionlist` xml column with custom formulas.

So far I have written this, which works, but is incredibly slow (more than a minute to get 5000 lines), and I would need to speed it up a bit.

```
select *
from [status] s
where not exists (
    select top 1 1
    from Wf_ActivityTemplate at
    where at.actionlist.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') like '%@GetStatusId("' + s.code + '")%'
)
```

The `actionlist` column looks like this (irrelevant nodes removed).
As you can see, I need to search in the `//ActionTriplet/Argument` node, which is itself an xml node stored in text.

```
<ArrayOfActionTriplet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ActionTriplet>
    <Priority>1</Priority>
    <Argument>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;string&gt;@SetProp("STATUS",@GetStatusId("INTERNAL DESIGN REVIEW"));True&lt;/string&gt;</Argument>
    <ActionCode>APPLY_FORMULA</ActionCode>
    <TriggerTaskCode />
    <TriggerTaskIsSecondary>false</TriggerTaskIsSecondary>
    <TriggerTaskConditionFormula />
  </ActionTriplet>
  <ActionTriplet>
    <Priority>2</Priority>
    <Argument>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;string&gt;@SetProp("STATUS",@GetStatusId("VALID"));True&lt;/string&gt;</Argument>
    <ActionCode>APPLY_FORMULA</ActionCode>
    <TriggerTaskCode />
    <TriggerTaskIsSecondary>false</TriggerTaskIsSecondary>
    <TriggerTaskConditionFormula />
  </ActionTriplet>
</ArrayOfActionTriplet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is taking the whole content of your XML, converts it to `nvarchar` and performs a `%x%-like-search`, which is always slow. The bigger the text, the slower...

To show another approach I declare a table variable, which mocks up your table, with two rows (see the ID). I search for the code given in `@YourCode`:

```
DECLARE @YourCode NVARCHAR(100)=N'INTERNAL DESIGN REVIEW';

DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, actionList XML);
INSERT INTO @YourTable(actionList) VALUES(
'<ArrayOfActionTriplet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ActionTriplet>
    <Priority>1</Priority>
    <Argument>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;string&gt;@SetProp("STATUS",@GetStatusId("INTERNAL DESIGN REVIEW"));True&lt;/string&gt;</Argument>
    <ActionCode>APPLY_FORMULA</ActionCode>
    <TriggerTaskCode />
    <TriggerTaskIsSecondary>false</TriggerTaskIsSecondary>
    <TriggerTaskConditionFormula />
  </ActionTriplet>
  <ActionTriplet>
    <Priority>2</Priority>
    <Argument>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;string&gt;@SetProp("STATUS",@GetStatusId("VALID"));True&lt;/string&gt;</Argument>
    <ActionCode>APPLY_FORMULA</ActionCode>
    <TriggerTaskCode />
    <TriggerTaskIsSecondary>false</TriggerTaskIsSecondary>
    <TriggerTaskConditionFormula />
  </ActionTriplet>
</ArrayOfActionTriplet>')
,(
'<ArrayOfActionTriplet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ActionTriplet>
    <Priority>1</Priority>
    <Argument>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;string&gt;@SetProp("STATUS",@GetStatusId("INTERNAL DESIGN REVIEW"));True&lt;/string&gt;</Argument>
    <ActionCode>APPLY_FORMULA</ActionCode>
    <TriggerTaskCode />
    <TriggerTaskIsSecondary>false</TriggerTaskIsSecondary>
    <TriggerTaskConditionFormula />
  </ActionTriplet>
  <ActionTriplet>
    <Priority>2</Priority>
    <Argument>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;&lt;string&gt;@SetProp("STATUS",@GetStatusId("VALID"));True&lt;/string&gt;</Argument>
    <ActionCode>APPLY_FORMULA</ActionCode>
    <TriggerTaskCode />
    <TriggerTaskIsSecondary>false</TriggerTaskIsSecondary>
    <TriggerTaskConditionFormula />
  </ActionTriplet>
</ArrayOfActionTriplet>');
```

--This is the query: You'll get back all `Argument`-elements, where the text within this element contains `GetStatusId("TheCode")`.

```
SELECT s.ID
      ,arg.query('.')
FROM @YourTable AS s
CROSS APPLY actionList.nodes('/*:ArrayOfActionTriplet/*:ActionTriplet/*:Argument[fn:contains(.,fn:concat("GetStatusId(&quot;",sql:variable("@YourCode"),"&quot;)"))]') AS A(arg)
```

## UPDATE

With this query you can cast the inner XML from the encoded form to real XML and get the full string readable:

```
SELECT s.ID
      ,arg.query('.')
      ,InnerXml.value('string[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @YourTable AS s
CROSS APPLY actionList.nodes('/*:ArrayOfActionTriplet/*:ActionTriplet/*:Argument[fn:contains(.,fn:concat("GetStatusId(&quot;",sql:variable("@YourCode"),"&quot;)"))]') AS A(arg)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(arg.value('.','varchar(max)') AS XML)) AS Casted(InnerXml)
```

### UPDATE 2: Faster, checking the existance only

If you want nothing more, than to check, wether there is an `<Argument>` containing your code or not, you might do this:

```
SELECT s.ID
FROM @YourTable AS s
WHERE actionList.exist('/*:ArrayOfActionTriplet/*:ActionTriplet/*:Argument[fn:contains(.,fn:concat("GetStatusId(&quot;",sql:variable("@YourCode"),"&quot;)"))]') =1
```

The final `=1` means: The string is inlcuded. With `=0` you'd get all rows, where this string is not included

Comment: Thanks ! Update 2 did make it a bit faster. I just changed `sql:variable` with `sql:column`.

Comment: @cosmo0, Just to mention this: If you are searching for this information more often, it is the best idea to create a side table (or one more column in this table) where you extract this piece of information (`TRIGER` for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. Add an index there and you will search in milliseconds...

Comment: It's just for an `update` during migration, but I'll keep this idea in mind. Thanks!